# Parsing MySQL Data to Android Application (JDBC)

Tags: android, mysql, parsing, jdbc

I'm currently developing an Android Application which connects to a MySQL database. For the connection I'm using the JDBC driver. For those of you who will suggest me to use PHP or tell me JDBC is not secure, I know the risks I'm taking and I don't have the opportunity to build a PHP page to parse data from there. Plus it is an internal network, so security is not in the big concern at this moment.

More details. I have successfully connected to the MySQL server via an AsyncTask and got the requested the data back, which I store in a String value.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(querybuilder);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
   while (rs.next()) {
      result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
   for (int i=2; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
      result += rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ": " + rs.getString(i) + "\n";
            }
con.close();

return result;
```

As you can probably see here, all my data are in a massive *string value*. I'm not sure, that the way I'm acquiring the data is the most correct one, since there are not only string values in a table but also integers and maybe some other type (not BLOB though).

Which is the best way to "split" the data? IMO manipulating the string value is messy, plus afterwards it would be very difficult to assign each string to a unique string.

I actually want to display these string values in a Spinner (or at least some of the values i.e 1st, 2nd and 3rd column out of 8 total columns in the DB table).

Any help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could make a custom adapter that receives and uses the ResultSet.

Comment: How would I separate the values from each other? Since I don't want them to display all at once.